# VHDL multiplexing seven segment display

Tags: vhdl, multiplexing

I am trying to implement a half adder. I am using a multiplexer to drive two digits on a seven segment display on a board with a 32 MHz clock. I want each digit (connected to active-low anodes 0 and 1) to be on for 1 ms. I am using a counter to try to achieve this.

The multiplexer code is below. Cmux and Smux are vectors representing the seven segments (plus the decimal point) for the carry and sum, which are being multiplexed.

The code I have written is below. I am getting the error FF/latch seg has a constant value in block mux.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity mux is
    port(Cmux, Smux: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
         CLK: in std_logic;
         Seg: inout std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
         AN0, AN1: out std_logic);
end mux;

architecture Behavioral of mux is
    signal counter: integer range 0 to 32000 := 0;
begin
    process(CLK)
    begin
        if CLK'event and CLK='1' then
            if counter = 32000 then
                if Seg = Cmux then
                    Seg <= Smux;
                    AN0 <= '1';
                    AN1 <= '0';
                else
                    if Seg = Smux then
                        Seg <= Cmux;
                        AN0 <= '0';
                        AN1 <= '1';
                    else
                        Seg <= Smux;
                        AN0 <= '1';
                        AN1 <= '0';
                    end if;
                    counter <= 0;
                end if;
            else
                counter <= counter + 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: `else if` -> `elsif`. And I fixed you indentation. See the assignment problem?

Comment: @JHBonarius I guess it refers to the entity name.

Comment: @mkrieger1 oops. lets' quickly delete my comment :P

Comment: The approach is kind of flawed. The decision on what to display next should not depend on what is currently displayed (in other words, `Seg` should be an `out` port, not `inout`). Instead, there should be another signal that toggles between two values whenever `counter = 32000` and that signal should be used to multiplex either `(Smux, 1, 0)` or `(Cmux, 0, 1)` to the outputs `(Seg, AN0, AN1)`.

Comment: Your suggestion worked perfectly. Thank you. I added another signal for toggling as you suggested, and another process which assigns values to Seg and the anodes according to the toggle value.